# RSelenium unknown error when clickElement() function is called

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I want to scrape holidayiq.com hotel review data, for example [hotel review link](http://www.holidayiq.com/Royal-Himalayan-Club-Shimla-hotel-429980.html), using R package 'Rvest'. 'RSelenium' is used for clicking on the "Next >" link, to visit further pages.

Whenever I use the code 
`nxtButton = mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#next")
nxtButton$clickElement()`
to visit the next page I get the following error:

[Snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM1Si.png)

Please tell me how to deal with this error. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Post the actual code and error itself instead of linking a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work.

Your css element is not found in the page.

`nxtButton = mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#submit_form")
nxtButton$clickElement()`

I guess you wanted to click the button NEXT in the right side form in the link provided above.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to click the next button below the reviews section, to go to the next page reviews... Please provide me the proper css element. I have already used the css selector - "#next", but it is not working too.

Comment: I changed my default browser to phantomJS (from chrome), and this solved the problem. Code is now running smoothly. Thanks for help anyways.